# Copy unique values via vba instead of formulas

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am trying to copy the input from two columns **uniquely**(see image). So far it works to copy normal values to another sheet uniquely. The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to copy two columns that both exist out of if functions. When I run the copy macro via a button I get #REF because it copies the formula instead of the actual values. I read that pastespecial could help but wasn't able to get it to work. Anyone have any ideas?

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Business units & cat uniq
 With Worksheets("Data")
        .Range("AN9:AO203").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                             CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Overview").Range("A294:B303"), Unique:=True
    End With

ErrorHandler:
Exit Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Try looping through and storing unique values into an array then dump it back out?

Comment: Copy/Paste values then Remove Duplicates?  Record a macro while carrying out those steps and it should get you most of the way there.